Avoiding Circular Dependency when Calculating Inventory Projection
I am soliciting forecast feedback from users for a product/location/futuredate combination and am trying to merge this feedback with an replenishment table to be able to show a monthly projected inventory balance in PowerBI. Example Formula (as would be calculated in Excel): Month 1 Figure = InitialInventory + SumInboundPOsMonth1 - ForecastMonth1. Month 2 = Month 1 Figure + SumInboundPOMonth2 - ForecastMonth2. Month 3 = Month 2 Figure + SumInboundPOMonth3 - ForecastMonth3, etc.
My issue in PowerBI is that I continue to run into circular dependency issues when referring to the forecast from the month prior in PowerBI. I've tried creating separate tables, calculated columns, measures, etc to no avail





Power BI works differently to Excel and you cannot use a calculation upon itself. There are ways to approach this differently. Update your question with details on your DAX code and data model set-up.
